# Using a list of dictionaries to associate letters with numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I am about a week into learning Python and I am very confused about making dictionaries (or if I should even be using a dictionary for this). I've searched all over for a similar problem, but it's possible I just don't understand well enough to recognize an applicable answer.

What I am trying to do is to associate a letter with a unique "score" (this score is a number). So for a toy example, for ABCA with scores of 1, 20, 10, 5...the first A = 1, B = 20, C = 10, last A = 5. The end goal is to then remove the letters with the low "scores"/numbers.

My data in a list is something like this:

```
x_list = ['ABCDEABCDE10 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1', 'EDCABB6 9 8 8 8 6 9', etc.]
```

Similar to the toy example, I want A = 10, B = 2, C = 3, etc. in the first string and E = 6, D = 8, C = 8, etc. in the second string. So I think I want to make a dictionary were the letters are keys and numbers are values? And then a list of dictionaries? What I am thinking is something like:

```
dictionary1 = {A:10, B:2, C:3, D:4, E:5, A:6, B:7, C:8, D:9, E:1}
dictionary2 = {E:9, D:8, C:8, A:8, B:6, B:9}
dictionary_list = (dictionary1, dictionary2)
```

And then be able to remove all of the values lower than 5 from the original list.

```
final_list = []
for each_list in dictionary_list:
   if value > 5 in each_list:
       final_list.append(each_list)
final_list = [[A,A,B,C,D], [E,D,C,A,B,B]]
```

I've tried looping through x_list with for loops to get the result, but I can't figure out how to get the numbers to line up with the values without using a dictionary.

Any help is very much appreciated!
(This is also my first time posting so please let me know if I make any newbie errors either in coding or if I shouldn't be using dictionaries at all for this.)

*Edited to improve clarity

Comment: `{A:1, B:2, C:3, D:4, E:5, A:6, B:7, C:8, D:9, E:1}` dictionary doesn't have duplicate keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem you are trying to solve correctly, so let me try to rephrase it. Let's focus on a single list for now. If I understand correctly, you are looking at lists that look like this.

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
```

Here I assume that we have exactly as many letters (or strings) as we have numbers (or integers).

You then want to associate each letter in the first half of the list with a number from the second half of the list. So you want to look at **pairs** of letters and numbers. As is it turns out, Python supports **tuples** as a data type and pairs are just tuples with two elements. To match up the letters with the numbers, you could do the following:

```
letters = l[:len(l)//2]  # = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
numbers = l[len(l)//2:]  # =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1]
pairs = list(zip(letters, numbers))  # = [('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 3), ('D', 4), ('E', 5), ('A', 6), ('B', 7), ('C', 8), ('D', 9), ('E', 1)]
```

In the first two lines I use slices (see for example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)) to split the list into two halves. Then I use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to create pairs from the resulting lists.

To then get all letters that are associated with an integer less than `k`, you could do the following.

```
k = 5  # or whatever you choose
result = [letter for letter, number in pairs if number < k]  # = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Here, I am using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to generate the result list.

To do all of this on a list of lists, you can wrap the code in a function:

```
def f(input_list, threshold):
    letters = input_list[:len(input_list)//2]
    numbers = input_list[len(input_list)//2:]
    pairs = list(zip(letters, numbers))
    return [letter for letter, number in pairs if number < threshold]
```

You can then use another list comprehension to apply the function to each list in a list of lists.

```
l = [['A', 'B', 100, 2], ['C', 'D', 12, 42]]
threshold = 32
result = [f(input_list, threshold) for input_list in l]  # = [['B'], ['C']]
```

Finally, dictionaries are probably not the right data structure for this particular problem. In a dictionary, you associate keys with values and each key can only have **exactly one** value. In your example above, you have two different occurrences of the letter 'A' and you associate them with the numbers 1 and 6, respectively. Therefore, using dictionaries wouldn't be very natural. (That said, you could define the value associated with the key 'A' to be a list or set of numbers, but I don't think that would necessarily lead to a better solution of your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each character to an ascii integer value using `ord`. In ascii, all of the characters values are right next to eachother, so something like `ord('B') > ord('A')` will always be true. You can use this to filter the list. e.g.

```
>>> [c for c in 'ABCDEFGHIJK' if ord(c) > ord('E')]
['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
```

Answer (score 0):

In dictionary, key are immutable. so, you can't create dictionary with repeated keys. Instead of that, you can create list of dictionary like this,

```
[{'A': [2, 7], 'B': [3, 8], 'C': [4, 9], 'D': [5, 1], 'E': [6]}, {'E': [9], 'D': [8], 'C': [8], 'A': [8], 'B': [6, 9]}]
```

you can achieve it by following code ;

```
x_list = [['ABCDEABCDE1', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1], ['EDCABB6', 9, 8, 8, 8, 6, 9]]
result=[]
for i in x_list:
    string=i[0]
    print(string)
    l=i[1:]
    print
    d={}
    for i,j in zip(string,l):
        d.setdefault(i,[]).append(j)
    result.append(d)
print(result)
```

after that, to get filtered list ;

```
final_result=[]
for i in result:
    l1=[]
    for key,val in i.items():
        for v in val:
            if v>=5:
                l1.append(key)
    final_result.append(l1)
print(final_result)
```

output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], ['E', 'D', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B']]
```